# Center of mass: Where is my mistake?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

(From UOC Paper 5 Mechanics 2 **M2**, May/June 2012)

The diagram shows a circular object formed from a uniform semicircular lamina of weight $11\,\text{N}$ and a uniform semicircular arc of weight $9\,\text{N}$. The lamina and the arc both have centre $O$ and radius $0.7\,\text{m}$ and are joined at the ends of their common diameter $AB$.

1. Show that the distance of the centre of mass of the object from $O$ is $0.0371\,\text{m}$
2. Now the object hangs in equilibrium, freely suspended at $A$. Find the angle between $AB$ and the vertical and state whether the lowest point of the object is on the lamina or on the arc.

[image]

---

### My answer

The centroid of a circular sector with radius $r$, and angle (in radians) $2\alpha$ is at:
$$
\frac{2r\sin\alpha}{3\alpha} \tag{1}
$$

The centroid of a circular arc with radius $r$, and angle (in radians) $2\alpha$ is at:
$$
\frac{r\sin\alpha}{\alpha} \tag{2}
$$

The $x$ coordinate of the centroid is given by:
$$
    \overline{x}\sum{M} = \sum{x_i m_i}
$$

Thus,
$$
   \overline{x}\,(11+9) = 9\frac{r\sin\alpha}{\alpha} - 11\frac{2r\sin\alpha}{3\alpha} \implies \overline{x} = \frac{r\sin\alpha}{12\alpha}
$$

Substituting the values for $r$ and $\alpha$:
$$
    \overline{x} = \frac{7}{60\pi} \approx 0.0371\,\text{m} 
$$

[image]

So now we know that $\overline{x}$ is on the right side of the center, and when the object is suspended freely, the object will rotate and $\overline{x}$ will be below $O$. Thus the lowest point will be on the arc. But the answer is it will be on the lamina. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Maybe your mistake is believe the answer is correct. I agree with your answer!

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: @JohnHoltz I am also confident about my answer. The reason I brought this question here is because I written to UOC and they said the board stands behind the official answer.

Comment: Who is UOC? Can you send me how to find the original question (either a link to a website, scan/photo of the written text, book title or whatever). JohnHoltzPE at gmail dot com

Comment: @JohnHoltz E-mailed you the relevant document.